# Copying multiple stored procedures to other database

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

In below scenario, I'm trying to import hundreds of procedures into other database.

Solution: SQL Server

Source

- SERVER: A
- DATABASE: Apple
- PROCEDURES: SP1, SP2, SP3 ... SP100

Destination

- SERVER: B
- DATABASE: Orange

First thing I did was find only non-existing procedures when compared to both databases.

To do so, I used `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` from each database and compared in Excel.

After finding a list of procedures to be imported, I wanted to import all procedures at once.

However, if I create procedure in one-lined text, it will be saved one line which has zero visibility.

So, I used `sp_helptext` to copy by line for each. Then, created little query like below:

```
create table #proceduretext (runquery varchar(max))
insert into #proceduretext
exec sp_helptext 'SP1'
insert into #proceduretext select 'go'
insert into #proceduretext
exec sp_helptext 'SP2'
insert into #proceduretext select 'go'
insert into #proceduretext
exec sp_helptext 'SP3'
insert into #proceduretext select 'go'
.
.
.
insert into #proceduretext
exec sp_helptext 'SP100'
insert into #proceduretext select 'go'
```

Then do a select from temp table, paste result, run.

However, above was still insufficient.

Please help with below questions:

1. Is there a way to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` for linked servers?
2. If there is an answer to question 1, how can I loop below query for all missing procedures?

   ```
   insert into #proceduretext
       exec sp_helptext 'SP100'

   insert into #proceduretext select 'go'
   ```

Comment: why just you not use task->Generate script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a linked server pretty easily. Here's an example I prepared for you. Run it from within the target database and change the [GREGT580] to whatever your linked server name is.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

-- Copying from [GREGT580] to local server

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @MissingProcedures TABLE
(
    MissingProcedureID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    SchemaName sysname,
    ProcedureName sysname,
    ProcedureDefinition nvarchar(max)
);

INSERT @MissingProcedures 
(
    SchemaName, ProcedureName, ProcedureDefinition
)

SELECT s.[name], p.[name], sm.definition
FROM [GREGT580].AdventureWorks.sys.procedures AS p
INNER JOIN [GREGT580].AdventureWorks.sys.schemas AS s
ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN [GREGT580].AdventureWorks.sys.sql_modules AS sm
ON sm.object_id = p.object_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM sys.procedures AS pl
                  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS sl
                  ON sl.schema_id = pl.schema_id
                  AND sl.[name] = s.[name] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
                  AND pl.[name] = p.[name] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT);

DECLARE @SchemaName sysname;
DECLARE @ProcedureName sysname;
DECLARE @ProcedureDefinition nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Counter int = 1;

WHILE @Counter < (SELECT MAX(MissingProcedureID) FROM @MissingProcedures AS mp)
BEGIN
    SELECT @SchemaName = mp.SchemaName,
           @ProcedureName = mp.ProcedureName,
           @ProcedureDefinition = mp.ProcedureDefinition
    FROM @MissingProcedures AS mp
    WHERE mp.MissingProcedureID = @Counter;

    PRINT @ProcedureDefinition; -- Change to EXEC (@ProcedureDefinition) to create

    SET @Counter += 1;
END;
```

I made the code just print out the procedures, so you could test it. Change the PRINT line to the EXEC option shown when you want to actually created them. (Note that PRINT will truncate what it shows if they are long but EXEC will be fine).

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Note that I tested it in tempdb. But remember to remove the USE statement when you run it in your own database.

Comment: Thank you for your help
I edited last part to use cursor instead because pulling procedure script from definition column would bring it to one lined text which didn't work for all procedures

Comment: Hey vay, it doesn't actually. That's just how it's shown in SSMS and other tools. You get back the definition as it was done in the first place. A cursor will make no difference.

Comment: is there a way to post a picture here? i'd love to explain the situation

Answer (score 0):

try using https://www.red-gate.com/ compare tool you can download a trail version. Works great

Comment: Very neat solution for sure but my trial ended :(